# How to fix a problem with substract position by grouping on some position

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In my xslt converter I have to substract some of position from one invoice and show it on group. I don't know how can I do this. Now I have xslt which give me a result in separate position.

```
<Invoice>
    <P_1>2019.04.30</P_1>
    <P_2>FV_0660/E/2019</P_2>
    <P_3>Client</P_3>
    <P_4>Client Adress</P_4>
    <P_5>3570.9200</P_5>
    <P_6>821.3100</P_6>
    <P_7>4392.23</P_7>
</Invoice>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position1</P_9>
    <P_10>1707.10</P_10>
    <P_11>2099.73</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position2 variable</P_9>
    <P_10>143.61</P_10>
    <P_11>176.64</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position3</P_9>
    <P_10>0.00</P_10>
    <P_11>0.00</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position4</P_9>
    <P_10>1086.47</P_10>
    <P_11>1336.36</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position5 variable</P_9>
    <P_10>103.46</P_10>
    <P_11>127.26</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position6</P_9>
    <P_10>384.38</P_10>
    <P_11>472.79</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position7 variable</P_9>
    <P_10>32.34</P_10>
    <P_11>39.78</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position8</P_9>
    <P_10>9.87</P_10>
    <P_11>12.14</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
<InvoiceRecord typ="G">
    <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
    <P_9>Position9</P_9>
    <P_10>103.69</P_10>
    <P_11>127.54</P_11>
</InvoiceRecord>
```

Now I get result

```
 Position1 1707.10
 Position2 variable 143.61 etc.
```

The result that I need is like this

```
Positions 3291.51
PositionsV 279.41
```

I need sum of positions without word variable and second sum with variable. Maybe someone can help me with this problem please.

Comment: Your XML does not have a root node.  And, it would be helpful, if you posted your code.  So knowing what you want is more of a guess.  That said, if you want to sum based on element position, you could do something like this:  sum(InvoiceRecord/*[3])

Answer (score 1):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <Invoice>
        <P_1>2019.04.30</P_1>
        <P_2>FV_0660/E/2019</P_2>
        <P_3>Client</P_3>
        <P_4>Client Adress</P_4>
        <P_5>3570.9200</P_5>
        <P_6>821.3100</P_6>
        <P_7>4392.23</P_7>
    </Invoice>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position1</P_9>
        <P_10>1707.10</P_10>
        <P_11>2099.73</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position2 variable</P_9>
        <P_10>143.61</P_10>
        <P_11>176.64</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position3</P_9>
        <P_10>0.00</P_10>
        <P_11>0.00</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position4</P_9>
        <P_10>1086.47</P_10>
        <P_11>1336.36</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position5 variable</P_9>
        <P_10>103.46</P_10>
        <P_11>127.26</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position6</P_9>
        <P_10>384.38</P_10>
        <P_11>472.79</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position7 variable</P_9>
        <P_10>32.34</P_10>
        <P_11>39.78</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position8</P_9>
        <P_10>9.87</P_10>
        <P_11>12.14</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
    <InvoiceRecord typ="G">
        <P_8>FV_0660/E/2019</P_8>
        <P_9>Position9</P_9>
        <P_10>103.69</P_10>
        <P_11>127.54</P_11>
    </InvoiceRecord>
</input>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <positions>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(InvoiceRecord[not(contains(P_9, 'variable'))]/P_10)"/>
        </positions>
        <positionsV>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(InvoiceRecord[contains(P_9, 'variable')]/P_10)"/>
        </positionsV>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <positions>3291.51</positions>
  <positionsV>279.41</positionsV>
</output>
```